# free software tool to Swap columns in CSV

Tags: csv, opencsv

QUESTION : I have been using Emeditor free version to swap columns in CSV.
But i want to know some Free software tool to Swap columns in CSV.

=========================================

Like

A B C
1 2 3

to

A C B

1 3 2

Comment: Why is this tagged as excel?

Comment: @Rawrplus untagged

Comment: @pnuts - i guess you don't have an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have analyzed these below tools, but either they have limitations or not working as per our requirement.

•   https://onlinecsvtools.com/swap-csv-columns
Swap columns works but while downloading the required file with swapped columns it provides a text file in Output.

•   Software - Swap columns in multiples files text software
Link - http://www.tucows.com/preview/1587003/Swap-Columns-In-Multiple-Text-Files-Software
Only supports txt files.

•   https://www.browserling.com/tools/csv-swap-columns
Worked for small sizes but not practical to use.